# Awk pattern matching syntax c&&!--c

Tags: regex, bash, awk

probably simple but I just cant find the answer...

In a Bash script im running this common awk one liner to print the Nth line after a pattern

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=5}' infile
```

This works and returns the 5th line after the pattern. What I actually need to do is return the 5th,7th,8th,16th,18th, and 19th lines after the pattern!

I can do this by using six Awk commands and cat'ing the results to a file and then using that as an infile for the rest of the script but this seems dumb.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this awk:

```
awk '!p && /pattern/{p=1;c=0} c ~ /^([578]|1[689])$/ {print; if (c==19) exit} p{c++}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

- `!p && /pattern/` - If pattern is found 1st time set p=1 and initialize a counter c=0
- `p{c++}` - If pattern has been already found increment the counter
- `c ~ /^([578]|1[689])$/` - If counter is one of 5, 7, 8, 16, 18, 19
- `{print; if (c==19) exit}` - for those counter print line and exist after 9th line

Comment: This almost works except it is not pulling those lines from after the pattern match, just from the beginning of the file.

Comment: Works! Thank You! Do you have time for a quick explanation?

Comment: Yes sure adding it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! Very concise one liner!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out, interesting problem that was. +1 to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd do it something like this:

```
BEGIN { last = 19; lines[5] = lines[7] = lines[8] = lines[16] = lines[18] = lines[last] = 1; }

f && ++c in lines { print; if (c == last) exit}
/pattern/ { f = 1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ seq 100 | 
  awk -v patt='^10|50$' '
      BEGIN {p[5];p[7];p[8];p[16];p[18];p[19]} 
      $0 ~ patt {n=NR} 
      n && (NR-n) in p
'
```

```
15
17
18
26
28
29
55
57
58
66
68
69
```

Comment: +1 as using the `in` operator on an array is absolutely the right way to do this. I posted a slightly different way of getting the same results that I THINK is a bit more user-friendly since you don't need to populate `p` explicitly for every line number you care about but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

A slight syntactic twist on @GlennJackman's example:

```
$ seq 100 | 
  awk -v patt='^10|50$' '
      BEGIN {split("5 7 8 16 18 19",offsets)} 
      $0 ~ patt {for (i in offsets) p[NR + offsets[i]]} 
      NR in p
'
15
17
18
26
28
29
55
57
58
66
68
69
```

Answer (score 0):

Print line 2,4 and 6 after `pattern` found

```
awk 'BEGIN {a="2 4 6";split(a,b," ")} /pattern/ {f=NR} f {for (i in b) if (f+b[i]==NR) print}' file
```

```
cat file
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
6 six
7 seven
8 eight
9 nine
10 ten
```

Search for `three`

```
awk 'BEGIN {a="2 4 6";split(a,b," ")} /three/ {f=NR} f {for (i in b)  if (f+b[i]==NR) print}'
5 five
7 seven
9 nine
```

This is easy to expand, just add number you like to the variable `a`

---

How does this work:

```
awk '
BEGIN {                 # Begin block
    a="2 4 6"           # Set variable a
    split(a,b," ")      # Split the variable a into array b
    } 
/pattern/               # if pattern is found and f is not set do
    f=NR                # Set f=1 (to prevent this block to be run 
f   {                   # If f is true (pattern is found)
    for (i in b)        # loop trough all lines to find
        if (f+b[i]==NR) # id line number found f + line in array b is equal to current line number
            print       # print the line
    }' file             # the input file
```